# Can AdaBoost discriminate the data?

Tags: discriminant-analysis, adaboost

Assume that you have an image $X$ and you want to search a specific small object inside the image $X$. It's only one object.

So you training an AdaBoost model with only one valid train sample and the rest of the train samples, they are non-valid.

After the traning is done, would not AdaBoost be trained to discriminate the data $X$ by doing a search of one specific object?

**Example:**

Assume you having 10 test samples

```
   Face
   Non Face
   Non Face
   Non Face
   Non Face
   Non Face
   Non Face
   Non Face
   Non Face
   Non Face
```

That means, that our model is only going to work for just that specific face, right?

Comment: I don't think much is going to work if you have just one example.

Comment: @Dave Why not? Sure, it would be a very "dumb" model, but I want it only to understand one specific pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the model may likely discriminate and identify the single object that appeared once in the training data, but not because the model learned anything about the single instance of the object in the data, but rather because it learned the object was not like the "non-valid" training samples.  Under your training approach, the model would become trained to recognize/predict non-valid objects and not the single object you're mentioning.  Future test objects that are similar to the single object that occurred once in the training data would be seen as an anomaly, causing the prediction to be erroneous - which is what can happen for binary outcomes.  So the model would predict correctly for future test objects that are non-valid, and predict erroneous for any objects like the single training object.  Erroneous predictions could be used to indicate test objects that are like the single training objects.

However, as some of the comments have suggested, you need to really load up on multiple images of an object to adequately train -- i.e., not one image.